# How to create multiple empty dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Instead of doing:

```
a=pd.DataFrame()

d=pd.DataFrame()

c=pd.DataFrame()

d=pd.DataFrame()

e=pd.DataFrame()
```

each at a time. Is there a quick way to initialize all variables with empty dataframe? Because eventually I want to use for loop to assign dataframe values to

```
var_names=[a,b,c,d,e]
```

Basically, I need to assign values from a much bigger dataframe to lots of small dataframe with targeted names(possible complicated names, just for easy understanding)

```
variables=[ag_2018,al_2018,au_2018,bu_2018,cu_2018,fu_2018,hc_2018,
           ni_2018,pb_2018,rb_2018,ru_2018,sn_2018,sp_2018,wr_2018,
           zn_2018]

for var in variables:
    var=(a portion of a much bigger dataframe)
```

These are my codes. Python won't allow me to do it showing error: ag_2018 is not defined.

I saw some suggestions using dict, can someone please provide more detail about how to apply it since I am not very familiar with dict. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you want empty DataFrames please.

Comment: @cs95 cause I want to assign values(type dataframe) to different names using a for loop. 

for example: var_names=[a1,b2,c3,d4,e5]. I want to use: for names in var_names to assign values to those variable from a much bigger dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have to make `n` empty dataframes and put it in a list, you can do something like this with the help of list comprehension.

```
n = 10

df_list = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(n)]
```

You can do similar with a `dict` so that you can make use of non int keys,

```
import pandas as pd
df_dict = dict(('df_' + str(x), pd.DataFrame()) for x in range(10))
```

Comment: Then how do I copy an existed dataframe to those indexes

Comment: Let's say you have a dataframe in a variable `x` and you want to make the 1st element of dataframe list as that dataframe. Then you can do `df_list[0] = x`

Comment: thank you for the help. what if the indexes are strings not numbers. How do I do that?

Comment: Then you have to use a `dict` rather than a `list` where you can make use of string keys

Comment: Can you please provide some sample codes? I don't how to use dict.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dictionaries:

```
df_names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df_list = [pd.DataFrame() for df in df_names]
```

Then typecast a dictionary using the two lists by using `dict()`  and `zip()`  by:

```
df_dict = dict(zip(df_names, df_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea with itertools:

```
 from itertools import repeat
 a, b, c = repeat(pd.DataFrame({'col':[0.0]}), 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a list of DataFrames, you should be able to do that with a list comprehension like so:
`[pd.Dataframe() for var in var_names]`

Answer (score -1):

You can try below two line code.

```
import pandas as pd
df_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
for i in df_list:
    i = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: if I want to assign a value(type dataframe) to a, what should I do? df_list.index('a')=df?

Comment: you mean you want to copy an existing dataframe to a?

Comment: if you want to copy an existing dataframe, you dont need to even initialise.
df_new = df, here df is an existing dataframe.

Comment: it will be better to provide reason for downgrade.

Comment: I know that. But if want to use a for loop on a list of none initialized dataframe, python won't allow me to do that. I modified the question a little bit. Hope it will make my question more clear.

Comment: please if you can provide your subset of big dataframe and how/which portion you want to copy than i will be able to help here. or may be i m not able to understand the question.

Comment: I paste part of my code on question description. Hope it will help.